# ID function issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am supposed to create a class that has A unique ID for each object (starts at 0). It should also automatically assign it a unique ID every time a new object is created.
Hints (The constructor of the class should automatically assign the ID of the Geometry object. The data type of the ID is an integer and starts at 0)
My output is supposed to resemble

```
>>>geo1 = Geometry()
>>>geo1.id
0
>>>geo2 = Geometry()
>>>geo2.id
1
```

My issue is id seems to be a built in function that generates a random number. But my instructions say the number is supposed to start a 0. Is there anyway to make that happen?

My code

```
class Geometry (object):

    def __init__(geo, id):
        geo.id = geo1
geo1 = Geometry(0,1)
print geo1
```

Comment: You could define `id` as an attribute of the class yourself

Comment: `geo.id = geo1` won't work because `geo1` is undefined

Comment: Out of curiosity - why are you being asked to do this?

Comment: Your code has numerous issues. In your `__init__`, you refer to a variable that has not yet been defined. When you're instantiating the object, you're passing in an extra argument. The name `id` shadows the built-in name `id`. You also are printing the object itself, not its ID, so it's only going to output something like `<__main__.Geometry object at 0x00000000026329E8>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the next id in a class attribute:

```
class Geometry(object):
    next_id = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Geometry.next_id
        Geometry.next_id += 1
```

The counter `Geometry.next_id` is saved in the class, not the instance, so it will be incremented on each instance generation:

```
>>> geo1 = Geometry()
>>> geo1.id
0
>>> geo2 = Geometry()
>>> geo2.id
1
```

Answer (score 1):

`Geometry` could have its own 'static' instance counter:

```
class Geometry (object):

    current_id = 0

    def __init__(self):

        self.id = Geometry.current_id
        Geometry.current_id += 1


geo0 = Geometry()
print(geo0.id)  # -> 0
geo1 = Geometry()
print(geo1.id)  # -> 1
```

every time you call `__init__` the counter gets increased by one.

as far as i know the built-in `id` function can not be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Just to present an alternative using `__new__` and the fact that instance variables and class variables are not the same:

```
class Geometry(object):
    # create a class variable
    id = 0
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # Create a new object
        obj = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        # assign the next id as instance variable
        obj.id = cls.id
        # increment the class variable
        cls.id += 1
        # return the object
        return obj

    def __init__(self):
        pass

>>> geo1 = Geometry()
>>> print(geo1.id)
0
>>> geo2 = Geometry()
>>> print(geo2.id)
1
>>> geo3 = Geometry()
>>> print(geo3.id)
2
```